# delayed hide element after css transition completes

Tags: html, css

There are couple of similar questions around. But here's a little change in the case.

I am using CSS3 `transition` to show a small div in the bottom of the page. When I set the class `.show`, it slides up and when I remove it, it slides down and goes out of the page.

```
.bar {
    transition: bottom 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -44px;
}

.bar.show {
    opacity: 0.85;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: bottom 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s;
}
```

My problem is, though it goes away, it still is a `display:block` element. Which causes my body have scroll. Is there any way by which I can set `display:none` (using CSS only) after transition? Or some how convince `body` not to have scroll? (I already have `overflow: hidden`).

Since `transition-delay` don't work on `display` property. I tried visibility, but still the browser keeps some space for scroll.

**Update:**
Just incase we don't find any good solution, I've done it this way for now instead of `display: none`.

```
.bar {
    transition: max-height 0s linear 0.3s, bottom 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -44px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bar.show {
    opacity: 0.85;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    transition: bottom 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Can you set `overflow:hidden` on the `body` element, or will that not work in your case?

Comment: How is the element positioned... `:absolute`?

Comment: body doesn't have fixed height. Yes, it is `absolute` positioned.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the margin as following:

height of the division = x

```
margin-bottom: -x;
```

Not sure if this works but I think it should. Otherwise you might use

```
position: fixed;
```

Or the third possible solution would be to not let the division slide out at the bottom but on the left side. This can be done like this:

```
.bar {
    transition: bottom 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: `left: -100px;` would ruin my slide up/down transition.

Comment: Add a fixed position to the division, that is the only way of doing it without javascript. If you want it with js, let me know and I will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that could be useful, I've essentially implemented this via `position:fixed`, check this fiddle to see if it's something that meets your requirements - http://jsfiddle.net/7x0oajv2/

Second approach could be using `position:absolute` with a `overflow:hidden` on the body like so - http://jsfiddle.net/7x0oajv2/1/

Comment: `position: fixed` would not work since the `body` isn't always smaller that browser height.

Comment: I'm actually missing some context here then, `position:fixed` would place your bar relative to the browser window and not the body so it's position would always be at the bottom of the visible page independent of body's height. Could you point me to a live example or a fiddle to help you better tackle this problem?

Comment: Actual reason is, fixed positioned elements have very bad performance on some browsers. while scrolling, they sometime go along with the scroll and then sticks back to bottom.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change CSS dynamically you must use JavaScript or jQuery to change DIVs property.

E.g

```
$.("#myDiv").removeClass('displayBLOCK');
$.("#myDiv").addClass('displayNONE');

CSS:

.displayNONE{
 display: none;
}

.displayBLOCK{
 display: block;
}
```

If you just want to remove the div, call $.('#myDiv').hide(). You don't need to set display property to "none".

Comment: Well, The question isn't tagged in `jQuery` of `javaScript`.

Comment: I know but there is no way to change CSS dynamically only with CSS. I am sorry that I can't help you. If you find a way please post it because I was stuck with similar problem few mounths ago.

Comment: Actually there is a solution, in my case I can set `height:0; padding:0; border:none; overflow: hidden` and it won't take space in scroll. But I was hoping to find some more elegant way.